# My obj file is broken and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: modeling

[image]

I just started using Blender. I have been trying to fix this and cant seem to find why my obj file is broken i have the mtl files imported

Im using blender 3.1.2
[Heres the blend file](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/934395981494120540/967065768128831508/roblockz_rtx_on.blend)

Im using a HPpavilion x360 convertible 14-dh1xxx
Its like its clipping faces i have no idea how to fix this

[image]

I took the obj file from Roblox studio if that helps

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "broken", if you mean that it appears transparent, go into the *Material* panel, select the third material and under *Settings* switch *Blend Mode* from *Alpha Blend* to *Opaque*

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: It looks like some objects are flagged as "always in front" in the visibility settings